# Extracting the digits between letters in a file C

Tags: c, extract, digits

I have a text file which includes randomly entered numbers and letters.

I need to extract the numbers in file but not all of them, **only the first five digits**.

My text file has the characters:

> hg34h2g45hjk36jk6jkh34jkl34hl378l59k0567l60hlh67h98j496j46k90k1hjk1

So I wrote this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    while ((c =fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

when i run the code, it shows all of digits in the file.
This is the output:

> 342453663434378590567606798496469011
>   Blockquote

I'm stuck at there, what should i do from now on?

EDIT: Main problem has been solved, but is it possible to assign the output to a desired variable?

Comment: Well... use a counter? `int n = 0;` and before `putchar()`, insert `if (++n > 5) break;`

Comment: "output to a desired variable?" Instead of outputting to stdout with putchar(c), build up a string variable (char array), with `string[n] = c;` for the first 5 (n = 0..4). Don't forget to allocate at least 6 chars for string, and add a \0 at the end. Then you can do a strtod() call to convert to an integer variable. Alternately, build up the integer one digit at a time, `intVar += 10*intVar + (c-'0');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just count upto 5:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    int count =0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    while (((c =fgetc(fp)) != EOF) && count <5 )
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            putchar(c);
            count ++;
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You accidentally capitalized the `count` in the while loop.

Comment: [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)? You reminded me of my TC++ days! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of count. When the count reaches 5, break out of the loop as shown below.

```
int c;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
int count = 0;
while ((c =fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
{
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        count++;
        putchar(c);
        if(count == 5)
            break;
    }
}
```